# Show that there is no isomorphism between $K[X]\big/(X^2)$ and $K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, solution-verification, commutative-algebra

> Let $K$ be a field and consider $K[X]\big/(X^2)$ and $K$. I want to show that there is no isomorphism between $K[X]\big/(X^2)$ and $K$ as rings.

My attempt was the following:

**Proof** Let us assume that there exists $$\phi:K[X]\big/(X^2)\stackrel{\sim}{\rightarrow}K$$as rings.
Now using the prime ideal correspondence for quotients we know that $$\left\{\text{prime ideals of}~~ K[X]\big/\left(X^2\right)\right\}\stackrel{\sim}{=}\left\{\text{prime ideals of}~~K[X]~~\text{containing}~~\left(X^2\right)\right\}=\left\{(X)\right\}$$
Now pick $(X)\subset K[X]\big/(X^2)$. Then since $\phi$ is an isomorphism $\phi\big((X)\big)$ is a prime ideal of $K$. Since $K$ is a field this means $\phi\big((X)\big)=(0)\Leftrightarrow(X)=\phi^{-1}\big((0)\big)\Rightarrow (X)=(0)$ which gives a contradiction. Hence there is no isomorphism.

Does this work?
If not could someone show me how to do it using prime ideals?

Comment: Is there any reason you're set on using prime ideals?

Comment: @BrianShin no not explicitly but I wanted to do an argument on prime ideals and see if it works. If you have another one I'm open to see it but it would be nice to know if my argument works

Comment: Fair enough, was just curious :)  Your argument looks sound to me. I would probably argue by counting the number of (not necessarily prime) ideals in each ring.

Comment: @BrianShin No problem! But can I really do the last implication, i.e. say that if $(X)=\phi^{-1}\left((X)\right)$ then $(X)=(0)$, because this would be the only point where I think my argument could break down.

Comment: First, an isomorphism as **what**? For instance, $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb Q[x]/(x^2)$ are isomorphic as sets, but that does not seem to be the question you're asking here.

Comment: @KReiser as rings? sorry I haven't thought about it.

Comment: I'm just pointing out that your question is underspecified and you should [edit] it to fix that.

Comment: @KReiser is it now better? But does my argument still holds or not?

Comment: Forgive me if I'm mistaken, but isn't there a much simpler way of writing this? $X + (X^2)$ in the quotient ring is a zerodivisor, so the ring cannot be a field.

Comment: Your last implication is fine, but maybe it would be good to be explicit about where it comes from. To me, it looks like you are using the fact that, since $\phi$ is injective, we must have that it's kernel is the zero ideal. That is, we must have $\phi^{-1}((0)) = (0)$ in addition to $\phi^{-1}((0)) =(X)$.

Comment: @BrianShin yes exactly that's what I used.

Comment: @legionwhale you are not mistaken, that is probably the most efficient method to prove this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use the set (or space) of prime ideals alone. For every commutative ring $R$ and every ideal $I$ and $n \geq 1$, the projection $R/I^n \to R/I$ induces a *bijection* $\mathrm{Spec}(R/I) \to \mathrm{Spec}(R/I^n)$. It is even a homeomorphism. In particular, $\mathrm{Spec}(K[X]/X^2)$ and $\mathrm{Spec}(K)$ are homeomorphic. That being said, we need to use the specific algebraic structure to differentiate the rings. For example, you can use that $K$ is a field and $K[X]/X^2$ is not (clearly, $[X]$ here is nilpotent and $\neq0$  and hence not invertible). And clearly, this is much easier than using the prime ideals.

Comment: Sorry I don't get what is wrong now. Could you maybe tell me where my answer is wrong.

Comment: @user123234 I don't think Martin is pointing out anything necessarily *wrong*, just remarking on the fact that there's not really a way to use *only* prime ideals to prove the claim. (Indeed, even in your proof, there is one point where you must talk about a non-prime ideal.)

Comment: What Brian said.

Comment: @BrianShin sorry where do i talk in my proof about a non prime ideal

Comment: @user123234 That's a good question to think through, and I'd rather not spoil the answer :)

Answer (score 8):

$K[x]/(x^2)$ is **NEVER** a field since it is not an integral domain.

($x*x=0$ in the quotient ring, but $x\neq 0$)

Answer (score 4):

As supposed, $\mathbb{K}$ is a field. Suppose $\mathbb{K} \cong \frac{\mathbb{K}[x]}{(x^2)}$, then the latter must be a field. This implies that $(x^2)$ is a maximal ideal. However, we know $(x)$ is some proper ideal strictly larger than $(x^2)$. Thus $(x^2)$ cannot be maximal. Thus contradiction arises and there cannot be such an isomorphism.